# jcraft jsch + executing command on a remote machine

Tags: java, exception, jsch

Trying to run a command(ex:check if a file exists) on a remote machine but getting this error. Failing at this step -

> channel.connect(60000);com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send
>   channel request at com.jcraft.jsch.Request.write(Request.java:65) at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.RequestExec.request(RequestExec.java:56) at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec.start(ChannelExec.java:43) at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:152) at
>   SampleTest.jcraftTest(SampleTest.java:143) at
>   SampleTest.main(SampleTest.java:23)

Code i am using

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession("username", "host", 22);

Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "password,keyboard-interactive");

session.setConfig(config);
session.setPassword("password");
session.connect(60000);

System.out.println("session connected");

channel = session.openChannel("exec");

System.out.println("channel opened");

((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("uname -a && date && uptime && who");
channel.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect(60000);

System.out.println("channel connected");

byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if (i < 0) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
    }
    if (channel.isClosed()) {
        System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
        break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code!

Comment: @TestAu....Please format the code and follow the standards of `SO` before posting the code.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting.Otherwise users won't even look at your post.